# On converting xml to php array empty xml fields producing an empty array rather than empty string

Tags: php, arrays, xml, json, simplexml

I am using a nice, short piece of code to turn my xml string into a php array

```
$products = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($products_xml)),TRUE);
```

It all works fine except for when the xml field is empty when I get an empty array not string - and when written to my SQL database I see the string 'Array' rather than an empty field.

Is there a nice way to do this with php?

---

In the meantime I managed to solve the problem with this code:

```
$products = json_decode(str_replace('{}', '""', json_encode(simplexml_load_string($products_xml))),TRUE);
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the whole object into an array rather than extracting the information you want from it using [the many useful features of SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Comment: Also, why does only an *empty* array cause the word 'Array' to be inserted? According to your question and code, you're *always* converting to an array, so it would always result in that. Is there some further code iterating over the resulting array (in which case, as I say, you probably dont need the array conversion at all).

Comment: I just like working with associative arrays - array element names and SQL field names can then be the same - also later in the code I do sorting etc which is easier with arrays ...

Comment: What seems to be happening is that json_encode turns empty elements into empty arras: '{}' in the string - json_decode then changes them to php empty arrays ie 'Array()' which on writing to the SQL database appear simply as 'Array'.
By replacing '{}' with simply an empty string '' as an interim step between encode and decode I achieve empty strings rather than arrays at deeper levels in the final array.

Comment: If you edit the question to include an example of the XML you're parsing, and the array structure you want to work with, I can offer you alternative ways of preparing it. JSON, PHP, and XML have fundamentally different data structures, so the `json_decode(json_encode($foo))` hack will always have messy edge-cases. (I agree it's short, but I definitely dispute the "nice" :P)

Comment: I'm not sure I want to put you through this - though it's very kind to offer - much appreciated!
The reason is that I get the data from a third party software and the xml includes much redundant data compared to what I wnat out of it - it would make this whole post look very messy
And I agree that the short code can result in messy edges, but for the momeent I wil go with (you're right) not too nice code!

Answer (score 0):

If any field of content in your json_encoded xml contains "{}", this code will break. It happened to me, I am working on a solution to prevent that.

Comment: Where is the solution?

Comment: I must say I don't have it for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeElementArrays($array) {
        $temp = [];
        foreach ($array as $record){
            $ta = [];
            foreach ($record as $k=>$v) {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    $ta[$k]='';
                } else {
                    $ta[$k]=$v;
                }
            }
            array_push($temp, $ta);
        }
        return $temp;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your answer, to better describe the code.